# Two anchor.hash properties differ, but js disagrees

Tags: javascript, html

In a html page I'm trying to compare the hash property of two anchor elements, but even when the strings are different, javascript still returns true.

### HTML

```html
<body>
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
  <a href="#link0">link0</a>
  <a href="#link1">link1</a>
  <a href="#link2">link2</a>
  <a href="#link3">link3</a>
  <a href="#link4">link4</a>
</nav>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
</body>
```

### JS

```js
let currPg = 0;

function myFunction() {
  let currPg = 0;
  let pages = document.getElementById('navbar').getElementsByTagName('a');
  location.hash = 'link2';

  for (i = 0; i < pages.length; ++i) {
    if (location.hash == pages[i].hash); {
      //this always gets hit, even when they're different strings
      currPg = i;
    }
  }
  //just for the demo
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currPg;
}
```

I've been fiddling with it, here: https://jsfiddle.net/danobdgz/1/

Comment: what is `location.hash`? is it referring to window location object?

Comment: location.hash is short for window.location.hash, which refers to the current window's anchor location. So, if the current url reads `http://mywebsite.com/#home` then location.hash would be `#home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a semicolon in the end of this line:

```
if (location.hash == pages[i].hash);
```

:)

Comment: I feel ashamed for wasting space on StackOverflow for that... thanks for pointing that out haha.

Comment: @slanden haha, we've always been spending time debugging issues like this. Maybe you need a better code editor :D

Comment: You're probably right, I'm still using notepad++ XD

Answer (score 1):

Try wit this code there is an additional semicolan

```
function myFunction() {
  let currPg = 0;
  let pages = document.getElementById('navbar').getElementsByTagName('a');
  location.hash = 'link2';

  for (i = 0; i < pages.length; ++i) {
    if (location.hash == pages[i].hash){
      //this always gets hit, even when they're different strings
      currPg = i;
    }
  }
  //just for the demo
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currPg;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I was replying to Shu Ding before I saw your response.

Comment: :) My Pleasure. I just tried your code and i got same problem after that only i realized.